# Windows-1257 to UTF-8 database

Tags: php, mysql, database, encoding, utf-8

I want to change my entire system from windows-1257 to utf-8 encoding..

But i'm facing some problems,
When I change `AddDefaultCharset` from `windows-1257` to `utf-8` (in .htaccess)

- It changes from (I want utf-8 result like this): 
   [image] 
  Mūsdienu civilizētajā pasaulē par valsti spriež pēc tā, kā tajā
  izturas pret saviem visneaizsargātākajiem sabiedrības locekļiem.
- To this:
  [image] 
   M�sdienu
  civiliz�taj� pasaul� par valsti sprie� p�c t�, k� taj� izturas pret
  saviem visneaizsarg�t�kajiem sabiedr�bas locek�iem.

HTML meta tag can be windows-1257 and UTF-8 (now it's utf-8) - it works fine with  `AddDefaultCharset windows-1257`

 
In database content looks like this: `Mûsdienu civilizçtajâ pasaulç par valsti sprieþ pçc tâ, kâ tajâ izturas pret saviem visneaizsargâtâkajiem sabiedrîbas locekïiem.`

I've tried:

- Change content in database with iconv
- Alter
  database/table + "CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE
  utf8_unicode_ci;"
  (Maybe I used the functions wrong..)

Thank you for your time!

Comment: `AddDefaultCharset` and/or the meta charset just tell the client what encoding your data is supposedly in. You also need to actually *output* data in that encoding, otherwise you get a mismatch (as you see). Mostly you need to save your source code in UTF-8 if it contains any "exotic" (non-ASCII) characters and you need to retrieve your data from the database in UTF-8 by setting the **connection encoding.**

Comment: @deceze I added `mysql_query("SET character_set_connection =  'UTF8'") or die(mysql_error());` to database file and `AddDefaultCharset utf-8` to .htaccess - as you said.. but still output is "M�sdienu ..."

Comment: That call is incorrect, the charset is not a string. Also, use `mysql_set_charset('utf8')`.

Comment: @deceze Oh.. now it outputs it like it's in database.. `Mûsdienu civilizçtajâ pasaulç par valsti sprieþ pçc tâ, kâ tajâ izturas pret saviem visneaizsargâtâkajiem sabiedrîbas locekïiem`

Comment: You may be interested in: [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/)

Comment: @deceze so, texts are stored in `latin1`, i can make them work by setting `Content-Type` to  `windows-1257`.. but the thing is  - if it's in `latin1` in database, it's unreal to get `ûçâ` as `ūēā` with `utf-8` on `Content-Type`?

Comment: How the data is *stored* in your database is not immediately relevant. The database will return (and expect) the data in whatever encoding you specify as the connection encoding. The browser will interpret the data in whatever encoding you tell it to.

Comment: @deaceze thank you, Sir for enlightening me! Sorry, i have another question... If now content is in as `latin1`, can i somehow change all table/database content as `utf8_bin`? so `ā` now would be `Ä` - and  `utf-8` would read it fine?

Comment: "ā" does not become "Ä" in UTF-8. You may want to read my other article about the basics of encodings. Changing the encoding of how data is stored in the database just changes the details of the underlying bytes, it does not change the character (if you do it correctly).